# jquery else if always stops at the first else if

Tags: jquery

I want to change margin-bottom based on table rows. But the else if statement always stops at the first else if, which is margin-bottom:50px. Below is my code. Someone please help?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

if ($('table.variations > tbody > tr').length = 0){
    $('div[itemprop="description"]').css('margin-bottom','0');
} else if ($('table.variations > tbody > tr').length = 1){
    $('div[itemprop="description"]').css('margin-bottom','50px');
} else if ($('table.variations > tbody > tr').length = 2){
    $('div[itemprop="description"]').css('margin-bottom','100px');
} else {
    $('div[itemprop="description"]').css('margin-bottom','200px');
}
```

})

Comment: share ur html structure to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparisons should be `==` or preferably `===`, not `=`.  You are assigning, not comparing when you use `=`.

It should be this:

```
if ($('table.variations > tbody > tr').length === 0){
    $('div[itemprop="description"]').css('margin-bottom','0');
} else if ($('table.variations > tbody > tr').length === 1){
    $('div[itemprop="description"]').css('margin-bottom','50px');
} else if ($('table.variations > tbody > tr').length === 2){
    $('div[itemprop="description"]').css('margin-bottom','100px');
} else {
    $('div[itemprop="description"]').css('margin-bottom','200px');
}
```

---

Though, it can be made a lot more efficient like this:

```
var margin;
switch($('table.variations > tbody > tr').length) {
   case 0:
       margin = 0;
       break;
   case 1:
       margin = 50;
       break;
   case 2:
       margin = 100;
       break;
   default:
       margin = 200;
       break;
}
$('div[itemprop="description"]').css('margin-bottom', margin + "px");
```

Notice how there is no copied code and no selectors being evaluated more than once.

---

Another way of doing it would be to use a lookup table:

```
var marginValues = {0: "0px", 1: "50px", 2: "100px"};
var margin = marginValues[$('table.variations > tbody > tr').length];
if (!margin) {
    margin = "200px";
}
$('div[itemprop="description"]').css('margin-bottom', margin);
```

---

Or, this can even be done with a computation:

```
var margin, len = $('table.variations > tbody > tr').length;
if (len <= 2) {
     margin = len * 50;
} else {
     margin = 200;
}
$('div[itemprop="description"]').css('margin-bottom', margin + "px");
```